# How to see the implement of standard library of C/C++ by VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, std

I want to see the implement details of some functions like "strcmp strcpy atoi" by VisualStudio

I press F12 or jump to definition
But I just can see the code below can not see the implement details

```
_Check_return_ int     __cdecl strcmp(_In_z_ const char * _Str1, _In_z_ const char * _Str2);
```

How to see the implement of standard library of C/C++ by VisualStudio?

Comment: You probably cannot. You want a free software `libc` to see such implementation details. You might be interested by Linux.

Comment: Write a program with the call.  Break just before the call.  Select view disassembly.  Press F11  until the code steps into strcmp.   It is the same for all other routines  in the C library.  Many of them have been implemented in assembler to improve efficiency.

Comment: How to see the implement details by linux? I just know "man strcmp" to see the api doc  @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: On Linux you can always get the source code of [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) and look inside them!

Comment: This link may be useful - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c

Answer (score 3):

Express edition users don't have access to the source code. But the Community edition includes it, if you don't want to spend money.

You can find it after the installation in: `%VCINSTALLDIR%\crt\src`. If you don't want to navigate to the folder manually, open the `Developer Command Prompt` and then execute `explorer %VCINSTALLDIR%\crt\src`.

Debugging your program and stepping into such functions should also work as Visual Studio then opens the source file with the implementation. That's mostly why VS ships with it.

But this isn't all the source code. Mathematical functions (what's known as libm in the *nix world) are not included. You also can't *just* build it.